# The slope of the tangent which touches both the parabolas $y^2 = 4ax$ and the parabola $ x^2=-32y$

Tags: conic-sections

The slope of the  tangent which touches both the parabolas $y^2$ = $4ax$ and the parabola  $x^2=-32y$ how do we find the slope of common tangent if I assume the slope of one of the cords and  I find the relation that would hold between the two or should start some other way round  because I cannot understand how would this happen thanks in advance .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: A tangent to the parabola $y^2=4ax$ is of the form: 
$$y=mx+\frac{a}{m}$$
As this must also be the tangent to the second parabola $x^2=-32y$ , the discriminant of the quadratic equation formed when we put $y=mx+\frac{a}{m}$ in $x^2=-32y$ must be $0$.

Comment: that is what I am unable to understand how come the slope of the tangent be mx+a/m form plz elaborate this @Nikunj

Comment: Do this: Take a general equation of a line as $y=mx+c$, Put it in the equation of a parabola $y^2=4ax$, you will get something like $(mx+c)^2=4ax$ as the tangent intersects the parabola only at one point, the discriminant of the quadratic must be 0. So try to make the discriminant $0$

Comment: what would we obtain from there

Comment: You would obtain $c=\frac{a}{m}$

Comment: okay then we satisfy the same equation in the second equation and get the value of m from there right ?

Comment: You would have to make the discriminant $0$ because the given line is tangent to **both** parabolas

Comment: discriminant in the new  equitation obtained by substituting the value of y as obtained y= mx+a/m right

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: ok are there similar general equation for the tangents to ellipses also if yes please tell me because I am  preparing for the JEE this year and am practising this topic right now